# Language switcher list without button

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a list of available languages and I am not able to as close I got to was this but the language upon choosing is not being changed, the page refreshes but nothing.

```html
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post" style="display: inline;">{% csrf_token %}
    <div style="display: inline;">
        <select name="language" onchange="javascript:form.submit()">
            {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                <option value="{{ lang.0 }}"{% ifequal LANGUAGE_CODE lang.0 %} selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>{{ lang.1 }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

I get this error in log

- POST /i18n/setlang/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

I have tried to make it as a list with button but thats just ugly to have a button to change the language with.

Update:
It changes to other language but once on the other language I cant change it back.
For some reason , set lang is being called twice in url.

```
"POST /i18n/setlangsetlang/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
<div class=" float-right">
          {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
          <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                  <select name="language" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                  {% for language in languages %}
                  <option value="{{ language.code }}"
                      {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                      {{ language.name_local }}
                  </option>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </select>
              </div>
              </form>
        </div>
```

For some reason the set language is being called twice

"POST /i18n/setlangsetlang/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Comment: 302 is a redirect, maybe checking where you are being redirect can help you find the error

Comment: @luis.parravicini yeah it directs now to other language but doesnt go back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper answer to this is this that no one was able to provide.

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" class="">
      </br>
      <div class="language-footer">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <select name="language" class="nice-select lan_pack" onchange="this.form.submit()">
          {% for language in languages %}
          <option value="{{ language.code }}"
              {% if language.code = LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
              {{ language.name }}
          </option>
          {% endfor %}
          </select>
      </div>
    </form>
```